# How can I receive form data in callback with post value in controller?

Tags: php, callback, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, swap

I'm trying verify online payment.

After I connect to **bank getway** by using `function actionToken` and pay, bank send me some information to verify payment with `POST` method, but I can't receive the information with `POST` method.

Here is my `payment controller`, `function actionToken` is for send data from my website such as **amount** ,and `function actionVerify` is for verifying payment that I have receive bank information. Here is my problem, that I don't know what do I have to do.

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\Order;

class PaymentController extends \yii\web\Controller {

public function actionRequest() {
    include_once('lib/nusoap.php');
    $terminalId     = "xxxx";                    // Terminal ID
    $userName       = "xxxx";                    // Username
    $userPassword   = "xxxxxxx";                 // Password
    $orderId        = time();                       // Order ID
    $amount         = $amount.'0';                  // Price / Rial
    $localDate      = date('Ymd');                  // Date
    $localTime      = date('Gis');                  // Time
    $additionalData = $model['notes'];
    $callBackUrl    = "http://dastsazkala.com/payment/verify?id=".$id;  // Callback URL
    $payerId        =  $id;

    $parameters = [
    'terminalId'        => $terminalId,
    'userName'          => $userName,
    'userPassword'      => $userPassword,
    'orderId'           => $orderId,
    'amount'            => $amount,
    'localDate'         => $localDate,
    'localTime'         => $localTime,
    'additionalData'    => $additionalData,
    'callBackUrl'       => $callBackUrl,
    'payerId'           => $payerId];

    $client = new \nusoap_client('https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl');
    $namespace='http://interfaces.core.sw.bps.com/';
    $result     = $client->call('bpPayRequest', $parameters, $namespace);

}

public function actionVerify($id = null, $check = null) {
//my promblem is in this function, that I cant receive posts.

if ($_POST['ResCode'] == '0') {
    //payment is correct
    include_once('lib/nusoap.php');
    $client = new nusoap_client('https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl');
    $namespace='http://interfaces.core.sw.bps.com/';

            $terminalId             = "xxxx";                    // Terminal ID
            $userName               = "xxxxx";                    // Username
            $userPassword           = "xxxxx";                   // Password
            $orderId                = $_POST['SaleOrderId'];        // Order ID
            $verifySaleOrderId      = $_POST['SaleOrderId'];
            $verifySaleReferenceId  = $_POST['SaleReferenceId'];

            $parameters = [
            'terminalId' => $terminalId,
            'userName' => $userName,
            'userPassword' => $userPassword,
            'orderId' => $orderId,
            'saleOrderId' => $verifySaleOrderId,
            'saleReferenceId' => $verifySaleReferenceId];
            // Call the SOAP method
            $result = $client->call('bpVerifyRequest', $parameters, $namespace);
            if($result == 0) {
                //verify is correct
                 echo 'The transaction was successful';
            } else {
                //error in pyament
            }
        } else {
            //error in pyament
        }
    }
}
```

In this `function` I receive  nothing.

Do I have to do something in behavior of my controller or something else?

Why I can't receive any posts in my controller?

General chrome:

```
Request URL: http://dastsazkala.com/payment/verify
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address: 138.201.30.123:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Here what I receive:

[image: Here is my respond from bank]

Comment: Could please echo the value of `Yii::$app->request->getIsPost()`?

Comment: @paul i echos NULL

Comment: `getIsPost()` returns boolean, how can you get `null`?

Comment: But it returns nothing. My problem is this that my function has no reaction for posts.

Comment: Try `echo Yii::$app->request->getMethod()`.

Comment: @paul if you mind I can show whole of my controller.

Comment: Try `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->getIsPost())`. But I'm pretty sure that you have GET request instead of POST, so you should use `Yii::$app->request->get()`.

Comment: @paul it response GET but my google chorome shows me `method: post` in network tab.

Comment: In bank connection sample they told that you will receive `post`, and in their example it's `$_POST['']`.

Comment: How could that be! I have never met in my life. Could you please post the `General` header of chrome?

Comment: @paul I edited my question

Comment: What is the source of this `301 Moved Permanently` status code? Did you tried restart your browser to clear this permanent redirection cache?

Comment: Just as @rob006 pointed out, you might post the whole code of your controller.

Comment: I put my whole controller, thank you for your time that you spend to solving my problem.

Comment: dastsazkala.com/payment/verify Redirects to www.dastsazkala.com/payment/verify notice the www!

Comment: @t6nnp6nn you mean my problem is here? let me change and test it.

Comment: @t6nnp6nn yes you were right, my problem was thta, thank you so much. you made my day.

Comment: @t6nnp6nn put you answer as a answer to rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this: **my website url has** `www` in the beginning, but there was **no** `www` in `callBackUrl`.

So I changed

`$callBackUrl = "http://www.dastsazkala.com/payment/verify?id=".$id; //add www. in the beginning`

instead of

`$callBackUrl = "http://dastsazkala.com/payment/verify?id=".$id;`

and I can receive **Form Data** with `POST` method from bank getway.

Answer (score 0):

dastsazkala.com/payment/verify Redirects to www.dastsazkala.com/payment/verify notice the www!

the query result:

```
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
```

clearly hints that there might be a redirection going on